# progress bar for a webview in fragment view

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am trying to make a app for android in eclipse. where i different fragments with webviews in it. but i want to show a progress bar when webview in loading but i could not getting it how to do it i checked many tutorials but failed to do so. let me most activity code here.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
//import android.graphics.Bitmap;
//import android.widget.ProgressBar;
//import android.app.ProgressDialog;
//import android.app.Activity;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class AdminTab1 extends Fragment {
     private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.admintab1, container, false);
    webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);  
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");  
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://ww.google.com"); 
    return rootView;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                webView.reload();
                break;
            case R.id.item2:
                webView.goBack();
               break;
            default:
               break;
        }
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebViewClient` has a lot of callback. You should subclass it and override `onPageStarted` to show and `onPageFinished` to dismiss it, for instance. Take a look to the doc, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

```
 private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, 
         // here show the dialog
      }
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         // here dismiss it
      }
 }
```

and in onCreateView use it like

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
```

Comment: sorry i am new with android development. can you show me how can i do that?. Thank You.

Comment: @user2966615 take a look at the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); OR     webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());??

Comment: ok thanks but when i put ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AdminTab1.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true); where i need to show the dialog. nothing happened!! and gave a error on show() method sorry if its a dumb question.

Comment: The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (AdminTab, String, String, boolean)

Comment: change AdminTab1.this with getActivity()

Comment: ok i did that and error gone but now webview loaded then app suddenly crashed.And it didnt show that dialog message.

Comment: post the stacktrace of the crash

Comment: havent seen anything on console and after crashing it restarts app.

Answer (score 4):

You should try this

```
public class About27Fragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_27, container, false);

    final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView_about27);
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Please wait, Loading Page...", true);


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            dialog.dismiss();
            String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
        }


    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.mx");

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: I recommend you add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers may be good enough sometimes, but code+explanation answers are always better

Comment: I speak Spanish, my english is bad. But i try explicate. This form is for call a dialog when the page update, back, forward etc. This form declare webView in fragment for call of Activity with .getSettings enabled see page on webView, the use the zoom in the setWebViewClient enabled dialog when update page show dialog, and dismiss the finish loading.

Answer (score 1):

**oncreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
pd = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
pd.setMessage("Please wait Loading...");
pd.show();
web_view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
web_view.loadUrl("ur site name");
}
```

**WebViewClient**

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl(url);

if (!pd.isShowing()) {
    pd.show();
}

return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
System.out.println("on finish");
if (pd.isShowing()) {
    pd.dismiss();
}
}
```

In this way you can implement Progress Dialog in webview.

Comment: ProgressDialog has been deprecated and will cause window leaks if the orientation is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get progress in percentage

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different
                // scales
                //Updaate progress bar here with progress int
            }

        });
```